# How do I set the text in white and bg in black?

Tags: css

this is what I have tried:

```
<table>
<colgroup>          
    <col width="65px" /> 
</colgroup> 
<thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th style="color: #ffffff; bgcolor="#DCDCDC">TAPE</th> 
    </tr>
</thead>    
</table>
```

But it displays a bg in white.
What I want is a white text "TAPE" in a black background.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do like this,

```
<th style="color:#fff;background-color:#dcdcdc">TAPE</th>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/7kPaV/)

or you can use your same code , only thing you want to do is add a missing `"` in your code

```
<th style="color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#DCDCDC">TAPE</th>
<!--......................^.........................-->
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/7kPaV/2/)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  <th style="color: #ffffff; bgcolor="#DCDCDC">TAPE</th>
```

to

```
  <th style="color: #ffffff; background="#DCDCDC">TAPE</th>
```

you can also style *all* your `th` by using CSS

like placing the following in `<head>` tag

```
<style>
 th{
    color: #ffffff; 
    background="#DCDCDC"
 }
 </style>
```

or placing them in external file and linking them to the page, Using CSS avoids repeating styles, and is a cleaner approach to design.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                    ______________________No need of double quotes
                                   |   
<th style="color: #ffffff; bgcolor="#DCDCDC">TAPE</th> 
                                  |____________________you can't use =
```

Valid:

```
<th style='color: #ffffff; background:#DCDCDC'>TAPE</th> 
                                     |______________ replaced with :
```

No need of double quotes

Answer (score 0):

use bgcolor outside style, its not a CSS property.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <body bgcolor="#DCDCDC" style="color:white;">
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
Just replace the "th" with the below.

```
<th style="color:white; background:black;">TAPE</th>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<colgroup>          
    <col width="65px" /> 
</colgroup> 
<thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th style="color: #fff; background-color=#000>TAPE</th> 
            </tr>
    </thead>    
</table>
```